# Reactivating “\clearpage” in LaTeX after turning it off with “\let\clearpage\relax”

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking

My document has a table of content in it. As i found out, after inserting one (`\tableofcontents`) LaTeX does a `\clearpage` by default.

A method to ignore `\clearpage` is the command `\let\clearpage\relax`, witch ignores it till the end of the document. Although i have no other command in my doc, my last page got erased. So i want to reactive `\clearpage` right after the toc was generated.

I am searching for something like:

```
\let\clearpage\relax
\tableofcontents
\*reactive it*
```

One try to do it with `\begingroup` failed.

```
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\tableofcontents
\endgroup
```

Any ideas?

Comment: the group version you have should have worked

Comment: Any idea why it did not?

Comment: Given your extensive test case and minimal working example:-) ?  no idea at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I am afraid, but using a minimally possible example (class `book`, just a dummy chapter and grouping as the OP proposed) -- it really fails :-(

Comment: @ChristianHupfer "fails" meaning what? This puts aaa th etable of contents and bbb on the same page: \documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\tableofcontents
\endgroup

bbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb


\chapter{xx}
111

\chapter{yy}
222

\end{document}

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Thanks for your comment – I was able to [find a solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176109/1425) using that!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, but it does that even without the `\let\clearpage\relax`; the problem is with the `\clearpage` that's implicit in `\chapter`, so there's an (apparently undesirable) page break in between the table of contents and the first chapter.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: 'fails' in the sense of 'having no effect' on the undesired clearing page. Probably Antal S-Z provided some answer to that problem.

Comment: @AntalS-Z: I suspect also `chapter` is to blame about that.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes well it only stopped the clearpage in the toc heading not the one in the following chapter, but that's not failing that's working as specified:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, I know now ;-) It is never too late to learn.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At least with the document class `book`, quick testing suggests that `\tableofcontents` *doesn't* insert a `\clearpage`, but `\chapter` *does*.  Thus, you have to put your group with `\let\clearpage\relax` around the first `\chapter` command (or whatever you have that's similar) after your `\tableofcontents`.  The following example, for instance, typesets on one page:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\chapter{Hello, world!}
\endgroup
And goodbye.

\end{document}
```

[image: The above document rendering on one page (without the page number).]

---

#### The old answer, which answers the asked question but doesn't solve the problem (and anyway, you should usually use `\begingroup` … `\endgroup` instead).

You can save and restore `\clearpage`:

```
\let\oldclearpage\clearpage
\let\clearpage\relax
\tableofcontents
\let\clearpage\oldclearpage
```

`\let` just defines a command to be a duplicate of an existing one, so:

1. `\let\oldclearpage\clearpage` makes `\oldclearpage` equivalent to `\clearpage`.
2. `\let\clearpage\relax` makes `\clearpage` equivalent to `\relax`, which is a do-nothing command.
3. `\tableofcontents` runs, with its `\clearpage`s doing nothing.
4. Finally, `\let\clearpage\oldclearpage` makes `\clearpage` equivalent to `\oldclearpage`, which is equivalent to the original `\clearpage`.

Comment: I dont know why, but this did not work...

Comment: @GaryKlasen: I should have realized that, since your `\begingroup` … `\endgroup` version should have worked.  Perhaps some command after the `\tableofcontents` is the one issuing the `\clearpage` – have you tried making the group enclose more commands?

Comment: @AntalS-Z: I had the same idea you and Przemyslaw had, but if there is no restore to the old `\clearpage` command, a call to eventuall second chapters fails...

Comment: does including external .tex-data causing one?

Comment: Okay, solved. Just followed your instructions, but used `\let\clearpage\oldclearpage` a lot later.

Comment: @GaryKlasen: I updated my answer to include a more specific fix.  And you should use `\begingroup` … `\endgroup` instead, if you can; it's cleaner.

Comment: @AntalS-Z: I like your answer. I remember, that I once wrapped the `chapter` command in a similar way, for all chapters to drop the `clearpage`. I used a `\begingroup...\endgroup` approach then.

Answer (score 2):

```
\let\standardclearpage\clearpage
\let\clearpage\relax
\tableofcontents
%\*reactive it*
\let\clearpage\standardclearpage
```

Comment: I'm afraid Antal S-Z got there first, with a more detailed explanation.