# How to prevent a new page after \listofalgorithms

Tags: page-breaking, algorithm2e

I'm using both `algorithm2e` (for pseudo code) and `listings` (for SQL-statements) in my bachelor thesis. But I won't have a lot of entries for both so a full page for the list of algorithms / listings is wasting space.

Somewhere between `\listofalgorithms` and `\lstlistoflistings` a new page is inserted, even though there is enough space to fit both on the same page:
[image: Both lists are printed on seperate pages]

**How can I prevent the new page?**

This is a MWE to reproduce the image above:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{My first chapter}
This is my content... Talking about algorithm \ref{alg:algo} and listing \ref{lst:listing}

\begin{algorithm}[htbp]
\ForEach{lines in code}{
    \tcp{do something}
}
\caption{My algorithm}
\label{alg:algo}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={My Listing}, label={lst:listing}]
    DO; SOMETHING;
\end{lstlisting}

\listofalgorithms
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Algos}
\lstlistoflistings
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Listings}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Chapters always start on a new page.

Comment: By the way, should your list extend one line, it will have the wrong page number in the toc.

Comment: [Reactivating “\clearpage” in LaTeX after turning it off with “\let\clearpage\relax”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/176107) But i really really want to advise against doing it.

Comment: Using a group to relax `\clearpage` did it! Thanks, could you post this as an answer (maybe with the reasons to advise against it) so I can accept it?

Comment: Additionally, could you explain why I'd get wrong page numbers in the toc?

Comment: I would say we close it as a duplicate, that way the solution is also marked.

Comment: The line to the table of contents is added after the list is fully output.